# ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 | MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Im facing a problem while trying to UPDATE my table:
`ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

Im understand why this error raising for INSERT INTO, but for UPDATE...

`UPDATE google_docs SET url = "blablabla" WHERE owner_id = "5026eaa4ebdd4e70ad76c7d71ccd44e4" AND spreadsheet_id = "1_InJACe01sVTNNsIMDdfZ2L-HnEU4rY5oP-w52aIX5s";`

Comment: Does this `UPDATE` invoke a trigger which performs an `INSERT`?

Comment: Precisely! I completely forgot about my triggers) Thank you!)